# Git commit command with typo and unintentional commits

Tags: git

I recently started using git.

I was supposed to commit 25 files separately with different comments, which were already staged (git add filename).
While running commit command for the first file, by mistake, I typed command - git commit -m 'comment'file_name  (yes, without space between the apostrophe and file name).

Because of this typo, instead of one file, this command commit-ed all files with that odd/ long comment, which is a concatenation of comment and filename. I did not git push this commit. I read on stack overflow running the command - git reset HEAD~1 would undo the last commit. I tried that command but it's not like what I had expected.
I wanted to restore that state where I was before running that git commit with typo.
Earlier

1. I was seeing that list of files to commit, that list is gone now because files are still in "commit".
2. When I try to switch branch it shows that whole list of files mentioning "Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches."

Any suggestions on how can I restore that original state?

Comment: No, I did not try anything else.

Answer (score 1):

There are three flavours of [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).

Assuming your last command was `git commit`, to undo it you must run `git reset --soft HEAD~1`. It brings your repo into the status it was just before `git commit`.

Comment: As I mentioned, after git commit, I tired git reset HEAD~1. Can I still try git reset --soft HEAD~1?

Comment: `HEAD` mean the current commit. `HEAD~1` is its first parent. After a successful `git reset HEAD~1`, the current commit changed and `HEAD~1` now means a different thing than before. **Don't** run `git reset HEAD~1` at this point. Use `git add` to prepare the commit again and commit it with the correct subject. Or run the correct `git commit` if you put the file name in the command line to commit only one file.

Comment: As PetSerAl, has suggested above, do you think git reset HEAD@{1}, followed by git reset --soft HEAD~1 will work.? I guess, git reset HEAD@{1} will restore head.

Comment: `HEAD@{1}` is the position of `HEAD` before the last non-readonly Git command you ran. It may be on a different branch and it may be the current position of `HEAD` as well. Git keeps a list of the positions of `HEAD`; you can check it using [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog); it is useful when you change branches or rebase. Not necessarily useful in your case.

Comment: If after the wrong `git commit` you ran `git reset HEAD~1` your repo is in the state before `git add`. The last commit has been removed (actually it still exists but it is hidden), the index matches the content of the previous commit (`HEAD~1`) and your files changed in the working tree are still modified. `git reset HEAD~1` doesn't touch them.

Comment: I didn't change branch or used rebase after that wrong commit, only thing I tried is git reset HEAD~1. And git reflog showing HEAD@{1} with that wrong commit massage.

Comment: With git reflog, if I'm seeing my wrong commit on HEAD@{1}, doesn't it mean that git reset HEAD@{1} will restore head from where I can try git reset --soft HEAD~1.

Comment: Please stop and read my previous comments. `git reflog` doesn't help. If you run another `git reset HEAD~1` you loose a commit. Run `git status` and check that you are in the state before `git add`. Resume from there.

Comment: Before git add it was showing list of all those modified files. Now I'm not seeing any of those files when I run git status as those files are in commit and this is as expected. May be I'm missing something when you say "you are in the state before git add"

Comment: You said you have ran `git reset HEAD~1`. This means the wrong commit is not the current commit any more (and it is not visible any more); its parent is the current commit.